# Assign unique subfolder routes to each user Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, subdirectory

I want to give each user on my application an unique URL like: www.mydomain.com/username. How can I achieve this? I searched on the Internet but most of them talking about assign each user an unique subdomain. In my case, what will happen if username is conflict with other controllers such as home or products, for example.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes are resolved from top to bottom, with ones on top more important that the ones down.

That said you should first put all your routes like login, content pages, etc first in the file, and them something like following

```
get `/:username` => 'users#show`
```

and then

```
root :to => 'some#path'
```

because root should be the last one in your file.

What above code will do it will route all request not matched by previous routes to `UsersController` show action with `params[:username]` set. So if a person goes to `/charinten` they will end up in `UsersController#show` with `params[:username]` => `charinten`.

To ensure that all user profiles are reachable you need to create a list of restricted keywords (ex. 'users', 'session', etc) and when user sets his username make sure it's not one of those. There are couple methods how to handle the invalid/restricted username, but I think the best one is to ask user to pick another one (same as if username is already taken)